# Is it safe to delete the pointer after dynamic_casting?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, casting, dynamic-cast

```
void foo(MyClass* myClass)
{
    BaseClass* pBaseClass = dynamic_cast<BaseClass*>(myClass);
    delete myClass;   // <-------------- Does this affects on pBaseClass ?
}
```

In general how `dynamic_cast` actually works? (does it work like a copy constructor?)

Comment: If you do want a copy (and assuming BaseClass is actually a base class) then `BaseClass bc = *class;`

Comment: If `BaseClass` is actually a *base* class, then what is the point of that `dynamic_cast`??? Or any cast for that matter?

Comment: If you're worried that deleting a pointer to a base class might not free the memory properly see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294927/does-delete-work-with-pointers-to-base-class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Note that `class` isn't a valid variable name, since it's a keyword. I'll call it `c` instead).

> Is it safe to delete the pointer after dynamic_casting?

Yes; but beware that both pointers are invalid after deleting the object that they point to. You can't use either pointer value afterwards.

> In general how dynamic_cast actually works?

It converts a pointer or reference to a class type into a pointer or reference to a different class type, with a run-time check that the conversion is valid. In this case, the cast will succeed (giving a valid pointer) if `BaseClass` is the same as, or a base class of, the dynamic type of the object. It will fail (giving a null pointer) otherwise.

If you were casting `*c` to a reference type, then failure would cause an exception (`std::bad_cast`), since there is no such thing as a null reference.

> does it work like a copy constructor?

No. Copy constructors are for copying the object. This isn't copying it, just changing the type of a pointer that points to it. A copy would look like

```
BaseClass bc = *c;
```

Note that the type of `bc` is `BaseClass`, not the type of `c` (which is presumable a class derived from `BaseClass`); this is known as "slicing", since the derived part of the object is "sliced off" and not copied.

Answer (score 8):

**No,** that is **not** safe. `dynamic_cast` is just a type conversion - both the original and converted pointer point to the same object.

It is possible the converted pointer will point to a slightly different address (if multiple inheritance is involved), but it's still pointing (in)to the same object - no object copying occurs.

**Edit:** I mean "not safe" in the sense "after you `delete myClass`, `pBaseClass` is a dangling pointer." It is still legal code, though. Just quite dangerous.

Comment: Why not? `dynamic_cast` either succeeds, then there exists an inheritance relationship which makes both the cast and calling `delete` legal (the correct destructor will be virtually dispatched). Or `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr`, this is also safe. The standard defines `delete nullptr` as no-op.

Comment: @Damon Added an explanation; I had a strong impression that's the meaning of "safe" which the OP was after.

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't consider one might try to still use the original pointer after deleting. Valid point :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with pointers, it's only the value of the pointer that is copied (i.e, just the address).

Here's a decent explanation for similar code

[C++ Does casting create a new object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669197/c-does-casting-create-a-new-object)